# TinyMCE link_list SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, tinymce, tinymce-4

TinyMCE gives the possibility to load a `link_list` inside the link window.

I'm trying to insert a PHP generated list, but I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data 1 tinymce.min.js:17:105005

The TinyMCE init looks like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  language: 'nl',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern codesample TR_image_from_server code'
  ],
  menubar: false,
  height: '25em',
  toolbar1 : 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
  toolbar2 : 'table | bullist numlist | indent outdent | anchor link | media TR_image_from_server | forecolor backcolor',
  link_list: 'link_list.php',
  link_title: false,
  target_list: false
});
```

The path to link_list.php is valid.

link_list.php:

```
<?php
require '../Database.php';
$db = new Db();

$dbData = $db->query('SELECT', 'pages', '*', 'ORDER BY id DESC');
$pages = array();

foreach($dbData as $i => $v) {
    $pages[] = array(
        'title'=> $v['title'],
        'value' => $v['id']);
}
$string = json_encode($pages);
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $string;
?>
```

Which results in this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Test",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "title": "Dit is een tekst pagina",
    "value": 19
  },
  {
    "title": "pagina",
    "value": 18
  },
  {
    "title": "dit is de derde pagina",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Foto's",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "Home",
    "value": 1
  }
]
```

I've also tried applying other headers (text, html, javascript), but the error remains.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What JSON is getting returned?  What does the browser show as the returned content from the call to your PHP file?

Comment: @MichaelFromin, see the edit, Ive added the JSON

Comment: and you see that in the browser's console as the returned data from the server?  Asking because I have seen issues where the URL is wrong so while the PHP (when executed) returns the right data but the configuration data is not the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while. The solution is to make sure all Keys and Values are in double quotes. Don't use curly or even single quotes. Example:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Test",
    "value": "20"
  }
]
```

You can test your output here: https://jsonlint.com/

Technically, numbers should not have to be quoted. I think that may be a bug in tinymce's link_list plugin.